# ES6+ javascript module export options

Tags: javascript, syntax, module, export, ecmascript-6

I've seen public exports of ES6 modules done in both of the following ways:

```
// method 1
export var getAnswer = function () { return 'forty two'; };

// method 2
export default function () { return 'forty two'; };
```

1. Are both of these valid?
2. If so, why do they both exist?
3. Are there other valid options for module exports using ES6 syntax?

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find the answer with my googlefu.  I'm concerned *only* with ES6 modules, *not* CommonJS, RequireJS, AMD, Node, etc.

Comment: I think the difference is `import x from y` vs `import {x} from y`

Comment: See also [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36795819/1048572) and [export const vs export default](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33611812/1048572)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

A year and some later, here is the best information I've found on the subject.

There are 4 types of exports.  Here are usage examples of each, along with some imports that use them:

## Export Syntax

```
// default exports
export default 42;
export default {};
export default [];
export default (1 + 2);
export default foo;
export default function () {}
export default class {}
export default function foo () {}
export default class foo {}

// variables exports
export var foo = 1;
export var foo = function () {};
export var bar;
export let foo = 2;
export let bar;
export const foo = 3;
export function foo () {}
export class foo {}

// named exports
export {};
export {foo};
export {foo, bar};
export {foo as bar};
export {foo as default};
export {foo as default, bar};

// exports from
export * from "foo";
export {} from "foo";
export {foo} from "foo";
export {foo, bar} from "foo";
export {foo as bar} from "foo";
export {foo as default} from "foo";
export {foo as default, bar} from "foo";
export {default} from "foo";
export {default as foo} from "foo";
```

## Import Syntax

```
// default imports
import foo from "foo";
import {default as foo} from "foo";

// named imports
import {} from "foo";
import {bar} from "foo";
import {bar, baz} from "foo";
import {bar as baz} from "foo";
import {bar as baz, xyz} from "foo";

// glob imports
import * as foo from "foo";

// mixing imports
import foo, {baz as xyz} from "foo";
import foo, * as bar from "foo";

// just import
import "foo";
```

[Source.](https://github.com/eslint/espree/pull/43)

Comment: Great list, but can you expand on what each type does, and what the differences are?

Comment: That's an excellent idea.  I want to be comprehensive with each explanation, but I haven't touched ES6 in a little while so I'm a little rusty.  It'll have to wait until I'm back in ES6 land so I can be sure of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 41):

Both of these are valid.

Method 1 provides **named exports**. The key here is that you can export more than one thing. This should be used instead of exporting an object with multiple properties. When you import a module with named exports, use `import {a, b} from c`.

Method 2 provides **the default export**. There can be only one default export. This is primarily used when you are exporting a single thing, like a `class`, or a single `function` that you expect to be used without any additional support. When you import a module with a default export, use `import d from c`.

Note that you can use both! so if you have a major, primary function with a handful of occasionally used helpers, you can `export` the helpers, and `export default` the primary. When you import a module and need both kinds of exports, use `import d, {a, b} from c`.

One other option is that you can get named exports by listing them at the end of your module, like so: `export {a,b,c}`. You can also rename them `export {a as $a, b as c}`.

I got all of this from [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), which is the best source for up-to-date es6 module information that I've been able to find.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Are both of these valid?

No, `export function () { return answer; };` is invalid, either you use default, or you add a name to that function declaration.

> 2. If so, why do they both exist?

They don't :)

> 3. Are there other valid options for module exports using ES6 syntax?

You can see a lot of valid options here: https://github.com/eslint/espree/pull/43