# When to use the default export in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new to ES6 and trying to understand why/how objects are exported. My code completely breaks unless I export my class as a "default export". Can someone give me a basic explanation of what exactly the default export does versus a regular export?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Javascript (ES6), export const vs export default](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33611812/218196)

Comment: MDN will probably have enough information: [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export). Did you read those pages already?