# React/Redux connect(mapStateToProps)() is returning undefined for this.props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm unable to get my `connect()()` component to map state to props and then destructure my this.props to connect to my redux store.

I get a console error that `const {items} = this.props;` shows that `items` is undefined.

Attached is a gist of my code.

https://gist.github.com/ericchen0121/6bc0654563fa71ab04dd69e0bfeb6668

Comment: have you tried console logging `reduxState.items` in  `mapStateToProps` function? Also try logging `this.props.items` in `componentDidMount` of `connectedItems` class. `items` props might be empty.

Comment: Have you tried modifying your `createStore`? Based on the docs the 2nd param should be a [reducer-like](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html) structure but you passed in the enhancers?

Comment: I've tried running this code on my machine and store is created properly. `reduxState.items` is not empty, I checked it in Redux Dev Tools. I'm going to look into this more in the evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the bug is. In your App.js file you want to import `Items` container using

`import { Items } from '../containers/Items'`

when it should actually be like this:

`import Items from '../containers/Items'`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611943/3546130) is a good answer regarding import/export in ES6.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the bug. You're right, I was trying to destructure Items `import { Items } from ...` when I was already using `export default` in the `../containers/Items` file.

Comment: Glad I helped :)