# Meteor can not find import module

Tags: meteor

Running this Meteor app is giving browser console error:

> modules-runtime.js?hash=2b888cb…:155 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '././lib'

```
//lib.js
let age = { // key.value pairs here };
let lib = { // key.value pairs here };
export {lib1, lib2}

//footer.js
import { lib, age } from '././lib.js'
```

[image]

Is there a problem with the import path?, if not, why the error? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import as "named import" which is why you need to export as named export:

```
//lib.js
export const age = { // key.value pairs here };
export const lib = { // key.value pairs here };
```

also your path is not checking for the "parent" folders (../) but current folder (./)

```
//footer.js
import { lib, age } from '../../lib.js'
```

See also: [Javascript (ES6), export const vs export default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-default)

Answer (score 0):

it should be written like this
`../lib.js` or `/client/templates/lib.js`