# difference between named export vs default export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

while going through es6 points i found named export and default export as details, can anybody provide details and difference between them.

Regards,

Comment: A simple google search brings several results. Like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Examples

Comment: thanks abhishek, i will review it and let you know if any query

Comment: you can also read the answer from this question. but the link provided above is enough.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-default

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek answer helped me please review @abhishekkannojia comment for more details,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Examples