# The requested module ... does not provide an export named

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to import a default export from a module in Vue 3 and I'm getting the following error -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/views/FlashcardView.vue?t=1648376545088' does not provide an export named 'FlashcardView'
```

I'm trying to import this component -

*** Flashcardview.vue ***

```
<script lang="ts">
  export default {
    name: "FlashcardView",
    methods: {
      flipCard() {
        document.getElementById("flashcard-container").style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

into my root component -

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
  import FlashcardView  from "./views/FlashcardView.vue";
  export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
      Router: RouterView,
      FlashcardApp: FlashcardView
    }
  }
</script>
```

According to this page - [Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './add.js' does not provide an export named 'add'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590951/uncaught-syntaxerror-the-requested-module-add-js-does-not-provide-an-export) I'm doing the right thing by importing my default export without the curly braces.

So... What gives?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error

Comment: So this code returns no error for you?

Comment: without the `lang="ts"`, it did

Comment: I still get the same error when I remove it. Strange...