# why does "import { React } from 'react';" not work?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Can anyone explain to me why

`import { React } from 'react';`

breaks everything, yet

`import React from 'react';`

works just fine? Aren't they saying the same thing? I've tried to find an answer elsewhere in documentation and on the internet, but I can't figure it out. I think it may have something to do with Babel?

Here are my npm packages if it helps:

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-jsx": "^3.2.1",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^4.13.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
}
```

Comment: @MattCarlotta yes, I believe you are correct, it is a dup. How do I close this and mark it as such?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### `import React from 'react'`

This essentially says "find the **default** export from the `react` module and import that as a constant that I want to call `React`."

### `import { React } from 'react'`

This says "find the export from the `react` module which is explicitly named `React`, and import that here as a constant that I want to call `React`."

### Why doesn't `import { React } from 'react'` work?

Because there isn't an export named `React` in the `react` package. [There is only a single default export](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/npm/index.js). If you do this, you'll find that `React` is `undefined`.

### But it doesn't even look like I use `React` in my code. So, couldn't I just name it anything I want, like `import Foobar from 'react'`?

No, sorry. You need to import the default and name it `React`. This is because anytime you write JSX code like `<MyComponent />` or `<App />`, this JSX code is transpiled and uses `React.createElement()`. So, you need to have access to `React`.

---

Helpful references:

- [ES6 syntax and usage of import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: What is "module" in this context? A physical JS file?

Comment: Best answer on this question on SO!

Answer (score 7):

The difference is between default exports & named exports.

## Default Exports

### react.js

```
class React {
  render() {
    // some code...
  }
}

export default React;
```

You can import the above file `react.js` in your project like

```
import React from "./react.js";
```

## Named Exports

### react.js

```
export class React {
  render() {
    // some code...
  }
}

export const Component = () => {
    // some code...
};
```

Then you have to import the above file `react.js` in your project like

```
import { React, Component } from "./react.js";
```

TL;DR - Learn about Default Exports & Named Exports from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611943/6141587)

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import),
`imports` work this way

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
```

What this basically means is that if a package exports something as a default, it should be imported without the `{}`, and with any name you choose. When when a package exports something as a named export, it should be used with the `{}`.

The `react` package exports `React` as a default and each package can have only one default `export`.

Answer (score 0):

The second one works because it's the default export from the React package. You can actually name it anything because there is only a single default export per module.

So, `import RandomName from 'react';` would have the same functionality.

Anything else exported is explicitly defined which is why the naming matters.

The other exports may look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    someFunction: doSomething(),
    ... // more exports
}
```

To import it, you would do `import { someFunction } from './path';`. You can see that we're destructuring (unpacking) the name from the export object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment