# how to export two modules in a single react js component?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to export the following modules but I am unable to export.

I tried removing the default and have used const but unable to export, so I had to make another child component to export.

Here is what I tried:

```
export default  withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(app);
export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(app);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript (ES6), export const vs export default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-default)

Answer (score 2):

You can not export more than one values as default.

In case of default exports:

- you can export **a single value**
- you can use any name when import

And for named exports

- you can export multiple values
- you **must use the exported name** when importing

So you could export one as default and one as named.

```
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(app);
export const SecondComponent = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(app);

import DefaultComponent, {SecondComponent} from 'module';
```

Or you could export both as named:

```
export const FirstComponent = withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(app);
export const SecondComponent = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(app);

import {FirstComponent, SecondComponent} from 'module';
```

Read more about [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(app);
export const AnotherComponent = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(app);
```

One component can be named, other can be default export