# What is the difference between the different ways of importing material-ui components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

From reading the material-ui documentation and online examples, there seem to be different ways of importing the same item:

```
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
// or
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
// or
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

What is the difference between the different way of doing an import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference occurs when bundling.  Using the named import:

```
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

pulls in the entire `@material-ui/core` module.  That means you bundle everything in the module (and all of the dependencies).  And there are a lot of components in [core](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/index.js).

Importing:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
```

Only pulls in `TextField` component (and its dependencies)

I would guess that other paths where `TextField` can be found (like `material-ui/TextField`) are for backwards compatibility with previous versions of the library.

Answer (score 1):

It is because they are exported differently when you `export default TextField` you can import `TextField`s like this,

`import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';`
Because you can only export default something once in a file.

But if you `export const TextField` you should import it like this;

```
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

[See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @David's answer. For most projects, any of the ways do not matter, **provided** they have tree shaking enabled. Enabling tree shaking will remove all the unused imports.

This is a subtle difference which highly impacts bundle size. For example, [Next.Js projects](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12557), where tree shaking has to be added via config explicitly.