# Export all objects from javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object that each attribute is a function:

```
{
  SetBtcPrice: {
    key: 'SetBtcPrice',
    options: { repeat: [Object], backoff: [Object], attempts: 10 },
    handle: [AsyncFunction: handle]
  },
  SetVenezuelanRate: {
    key: 'SetVenezuelaRate',
    options: { repeat: [Object], backoff: [Object], attempts: 10 },
    handle: [AsyncFunction: handle]
  }
}
```

I'm exporting it as `export default { SetBtcPrice, SetVenezuelanRate };` and I'm importing it in another file as `import ExchangeRates from "./exchangeRates";` Then in this file I'm exporting the `ExchangeRates` and another funtion:

exchangeRates.js:

```
import SetBtcPrice from "./SetBtcPrice";
import SetVenezuelanRate from "./SetVenezuelaRate";

export default { SetBtcPrice, SetVenezuelanRate };
```

jobs/index.js:

```
export { default as UserRegistrationMail } from "./UserRegistrationMail";
import ExchangeRates from "./exchangeRates";

export { ExchangeRates };
```

In another file I'm importing `import * as jobs from "../jobs";`, this gives me:

```
{
  UserRegistrationMail: [Getter],
  ExchangeRates: {
    SetBtcPrice: {
      key: 'SetBtcPrice',
      options: [Object],
      handle: [AsyncFunction: handle]
    },
    SetVenezuelanRate: {
      key: 'SetVenezuelaRate',
      options: [Object],
      handle: [AsyncFunction: handle]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I deconstruct the `ExchangeRates` object, so when importing `* as jobs` it gives me this:

```
{
  UserRegistrationMail: [Getter],
  SetBtcPrice: {
    key: 'SetBtcPrice',
    options: [Object],
    handle: [AsyncFunction: handle]
  },
  SetVenezuelanRate: {
    key: 'SetVenezuelaRate',
    options: [Object],
    handle: [AsyncFunction: handle]
  }
}
```

Comment: use `export default` combining the objects by spread

Comment: Exporting `export default {...ExchangeRate}` gives me: 
```
{
  UserRegistrationMail: [Getter],
  default: {
    SetBtcPrice: {
      key: 'SetBtcPrice',
      options: [Object],
      handle: [AsyncFunction: handle]
    },
    SetVenezuelanRate: {
      key: 'SetVenezuelaRate',
      options: [Object],
      handle: [AsyncFunction: handle]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`export const\` vs. \`export default\` in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const { SetBtcPrice, SetVenezuelanRate } = ExchangeRates
```

Comment: This gives me `SyntaxError: Error transforming /Users/otaviobonder/WebstormProjects/newTE/back/src/jobs/index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (4:13)`

Answer (score 0):

`export { SetBtcPrice, SetVenezuelanRate } from './exchangeRates'`

Your default export is an object with SetBtcPrice and SetVenezualanRate as properties.  You can destructure those properties in an export statement.

Importing them will be similar:

`import { SetBtcPrice, SetVenezuelanRate } from './some/path'`