# Is it possible to use a component that was defined in an imported .js file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

Using styled-components, if you have `Title` defined in an imported file:

```
//comp.js

const Title = styled.h1`
   color: red;
`;
```

Is it possible to use `Title` without having to define `Title` in the index.js? For example,

```
//index.js

import "./components.js";

render(
   <Title>Text here</Title>,
   document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, and haven't found a way to do it and I may be out of my depth in thinking of a solution. In this example, `Title` would be re-used many times so, if I have pre-defined set of multiple components, I kind of want to avoid having to define every component (Title, Button, Field, etc) in `index.js` since it's already being defined somewhere else.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are meant to be reused. You basically can export a component, let it be default export or named export and then import it accordingly in another file and then use it there.

Example,

```
File 1

export default someComponent;

File 2

import SomeComponent from 'path to file 1';

or

File 1

export someComponent;

File 2

import {someComponent} from 'path to file 1'
```

You can read more about export/import [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6).

I think you can also try something like this way,

```
import * as SomeName from 'path';
```

Then, `SomeName.Component`

Comment: So, I would need to write

`import { Title, compTwo, compThree } from 'path to file 1'`

? There's no way to just import `file 1` and then be able to use `<Title></Title>` or any other components within that file?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Header extends PureComponent {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              Stuff
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Then

```
import Header from '../component';
<Header></Header>
```