# How to declare 2 axios instance for different bearer token?

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-modules

I want to declare 2 axios instance,so 1 is for API call using `access_token`,another 1 is using `refresh_token`.

So I have a code like this:

**config.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosAccessClient =function () {
    const defaultOptions = {
        baseURL: 'my_url',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

    instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

        config.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
        return config;
    });

    return instance;
};

const axiosRefreshClient =function () {
    const defaultOptions = {
        baseURL: 'my_url',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    let instance = axios.create(defaultOptions);

    instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

        config.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
        return config;
    });

    return instance;
};

export {
    axiosAccessClient,
    axiosRefreshClient
}
```

So in my Request.js I do something like this:

```
import {axiosAccessClient,axiosRefreshClient} from "./config";

static async access(url,body) {

        return await axiosAccessClient.post(url, body)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            throw error;
        })
    }

static async refresh(url,body){
        return await axiosRefreshClient.post(url, body)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                throw error;
            })
    }
```

but when I run the app,it crash at the point of `access()` in `Request.js` show this error:

> _AxiosConfig__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.axiosAccessClient.post is not a function

**But if I do the following:**

`export default axiosAccessClient()` in `config.js`,

`import axiosAccessClient from "./config"` in `Request.js`

then the code work(which is weird),but by this I cant access `axiosRefreshClient` from `refresh()` in `Request.js`

**Question:**

Can somebody tell me why is this happen? I read all this example,but still cant figure it out:

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6)

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6) and so on

How can solve this?? Export multiple function from a single file

Comment: `await axiosAccessClient.post(url, body)` fails because `axiosAccessClient` is a function. You need `await axiosAccessClient().post(url, body)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `config.js` exports functions; you need to rewrite it so it exports the result of the function calls instead, i.e. the instances.

```
// change name of functions
function generateAccessClient() {
  ..
}

// create instances
const axiosAccessClient = generateAccessClient();
const axiosRefreshClient = generateRefreshClient();

// export them
export {
    axiosAccessClient,
    axiosRefreshClient
}
```

This way you can import both. Having a `default` export is unrelated to your problem, you just accidentally solved it by adding the `()` at the end.

Another way is to do this:

```
const axiosAccessClient = (function () {
    ...
})();
```

Same for `axiosRefreshClient`.

Now your original code will work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this is embarrassing. I fixed it and it should work now.

Comment: Really thank you your help!! and the answer is easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions (`axiosAccessClient` and the other) *return* an axios instance, but the function itself *is not* an axios instance (that's why you can't call `.post()` on it). You should create the two clients in the same module and save them as `const` variables, and then export the instances (instead of functions that create instances). It makes no sense to re-create the same instance every time you wish to make a request. The parameters of the instance do not change, so saving the instance is better.