# Cloud Functions: what is the difference between exports.function = vs export const function =?

Tags: javascript, function, google-cloud-functions, cloud

This is going to be a very elementary question but I want to have a clear understanding of the difference between `exports.function =`  vs `export const function =`  inside index.ts of functions folder generated from Firebase Cloud Functions.

```
  exports.function = functions
      .runWith(CONFIG.MEMORY)
      .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
      console.log("hi")
  })
  
  export const function = functions
      .runWith(CONFIG.MEMORY)
      .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
      console.log("hi")
  })
```

I understand both totally work fine, but for what reason is it considered to be better to use `exports.function =`  than `export const function`  inside index file at the top level of functions folder?

I read this [`export const` vs. `export default` in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6)

If it’s not at the top level of folder, I can understand their behaviors but what I want to know is how firebase cloud functions deal with `export const function` differently than `exports.function` when it’s at the top level of functions folder, which is at index file???