# What is the difference between "export const name = " vs "exports.name = "

Tags: typescript, eslint, module.exports

These two naming conventions seem to do the same thing:

```
export const name = [some function]
```

vs

```
exports.name = [some function]
```

However, ESLint doesn't like the second and complains with "No named exports found in module".

Someone asked this question previously at [Cloud Functions: what is the difference between exports.function = vs export const function =?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354337/cloud-functions-what-is-the-difference-between-exports-function-vs-export-con), but it was closed erroneously with a reference that really had nothing to do with the question.

Trying to understand if there is really a difference and/or how to get ESLint to accept as a valid export naming convention.