# TypeError: X is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning React and ES6. I Created a React ES6.js for using and learning es6 features comfortably and cleanly.

Then I imported this js file in index.js and used that way:

```
// Get Started
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const myfirstelement = <h1>Hello React!</h1>

ReactDOM.render(myfirstelement, document.getElementById('root'));

// React ES6 (ES6 stands for ECMAScript 6.)
// eslint-disable-next-line
import { Car } from './ReactES6'

var mycar = new Car("Ford");
mycar.present();

document.write(mycar.brand);
```

Also ./ReactES6:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
class Car {
    constructor(name) {
      this.brand = name;
    }

    present() {
        return 'I have a ' + this.brand;
      }
}
```

I am getting an error in the title of this question while running but compiler doesn't gives any error.

What I am doing wrong, please help me experienced friends.

Comment: You're not exporting `Car` in the code you shared

Comment: export default class Car {

Comment: change `class Car {` to `export class Car {`, since you use `import { Car } from './ReactES6'`

Comment: I didn't know that I have to add this keyword, It makes sense, thanks a lot all of you!

Comment: So, basically you have suppressed eslint warning (that likely warned you about unused code) to ask a question :) "// eslint-disable-next-line"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something with the way you are exporting `Car` from `ReactES6`. It doesn't show in the code if you are exporting it. You could export it using

```
export default Car
```

at the bottom of the file. Then in the main method import it using

```
import Car from './ReactES6'
```

---

Edit: Notice that I removed the curly braces from the import statement `{ }`. If you want to import something like `{ Car }` you need a `named export`. A file can have multiple named exports, but only one default export. Try reading about *Named Exports vs Default exports*.
[Here's a relevant SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6)