# react: can you import component with a different name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to nodejs + react and I guess this is a basic react syntax. I'm just not used to it coming from another language. I want to confirm if I'm right:

I am trying an open react project which is successfully deployed and works for sure.

In the entry file, `index.js`:

```
...some code...

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin/Admin.js";

...some code...


ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeContextWrapper>
    <BackgroundColorWrapper>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/rtl" render={(props) => <RTLLayout {...props} />} />
          <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </BackgroundColorWrapper>
  </ThemeContextWrapper>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

For the component `AdminLayout`, it is imported from `layouts/Admin/Admin.js`. However, I checked the file and there is no variable named `AdminLayout` at all, `layouts/Admin/Admin.js` is as follows:

```
 ...some code...

function Admin(props) {

 ...some code...

}

export default Admin;
```

There is just the `Admin` being exported.

So, is it true that in react, you can import a component with a different name?

I did some search but cannot any description on this small detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`export const\` vs. \`export default\` in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually not related to React but rather to [Javascript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

Since the Admin component is exported as a **default export**:

```
export default Admin;
```

you can indeed importing it using any name.

The line: `import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin/Admin.js";` is a shorhand for `import {default as AdminLayout} from "layouts/Admin/Admin.js";` where you can see more precisely what's happening there: you're importing the default exported module from `Admin.js` and naming it to AdminLayout.

You could as well have used a **named export** in your `Admin.js` file:

```
export function Admin(props) {    
 ...some code...    
}
```

or:

```
function Admin(props) {    
 ...some code...    
}

export {Admin}
```

In that case you must import the module using its name (and that obviously will also be the name of your React component):

```
    import { Admin } from "layouts/Admin/Admin.js";
    
    // In your render function you'll have at some point:
    // ... <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <Admin {...props} />} />
```

But note that you can as well rename an imported named export:

```
  import { Admin as AdminLayout } from "layouts/Admin/Admin.js";
        
  // In your render function you'll have at some point:
  // ... <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <AdminLayout  {...props} />} />
```

It is also worth noting that while you can have multiple named exports per module:

```
export function Foo(){};
export const bar;
```

you can only have a single default export.