# Using serverless deployment to lambda with ES6 /Node.js v16

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, serverless

Newbie question....

I have a locally working node.js application which I am now trying to deploy express to AWS lambda. I have used [this guide](https://hevodata.com/learn/lambda-express/#w4) to deploy a test version (which worked).

I  now am trying to implement my application which uses ES6 (and has type: module in package.json).

In my application I have added

```
import serverless from 'serverless-http'
```

but I cannot figure out the appropriate syntax for the export - the original was...

```
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

I have tried:

```
const handler = async (app) =\> {
return serverless(app)
}

export default handler
```

Error message received:

2022-11-05T15:50:25.962Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception

```
"errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
"errorMessage": "app.handler is undefined or not exported",

"stack": [
    "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: app.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "    at Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:979:15)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1137:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1143:1"
]
```

I strongly suspect I am missing some fundamental understanding - truly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Hi @derpirscher
"errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "app.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: app.handler is undefined or not exported",
        "    at Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:979:15)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1137:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1143:1"
    ]
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`export const\` vs. \`export default\` in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6)

Comment: Hi @derpirscher, thank you for suggesting this. I cannot see here what syntax I would use to make the export handler work.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the error is that you are sending a default export when AWS Lambda is expecting a named export.

The issue is the same as with all ES6 imports/exports:

```
// export.js
export default const defaultExport = "foo"
export const namedExport = "bar"

// import.js
import { defaultExport } from "./export.js" // error, cannot find defaultExport
import { namedExport } from "./export.js" // success, found namedExport
import defaultExport from "./export.js" // success, found defaultExport
```

So, it's like the case above where you're sending the defaultExport, but AWS Lambda wants the `{ namedExport }`. You just need to remove `default` from your export, and make sure you're building the handler properly. Here is a suggestion to do that:

```
const lambda = serverless(app)

export async function handler(event, context) {
  return lambda(event, context)
}
```

I've tested and it's working with serverless-offline using Node18.x. You can read more about exports on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).