# named and default export confusion in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, es6-modules

I am beginner at React and I have seen different implementations for pages/components. Could you please clarify me the differences between the followings and pros/cons?

**#1**

```
const Home = () => {
  ...body
};

export default Home;
```

**#2**

```
export default function Home() {
  ...body
};
```

**#3**

```
export const Home = () => {
  ...body
}
```

**#4**

```
export function Home () {
  ...body
}
```

I am not sure if `export default Home;` must be added to 3 or 4, but if so or there is an error, you can explain the missing parts. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ```export default``` exports a fallback value for your module, without a default keyword you export a thing (class, function, variable or etc).
Also it's possible to use both in sametime. e.g.
```import { thing }, defaultthing from 'module'```

Comment: Which one should I prefer in general situation?

Comment: @Joshua What about you? Do you have an idea?

Comment: For React components, I often use default export. So for a `.jsx` there will only be an export and only one component in it. It's not a strict rule, but I try to follow that. And for utility or service files, I will go with named export as I usually need to export multiple functions from them.

Comment: I think this might answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611812/export-const-vs-export-default-in-es6

Comment: Good explanations, thanks a lot. Actually, I do not know which one is which. Could you post an answer please by giving the types and the places where you prefer that type?