# NavigatorIOS Error - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigator

React Native

When I try to go another page i keep getting this error

```
goToMenu(){
 this.props.navigator.push({
  component: Menu,
  title: 'Main Menu',
  passProps: {navigator: this.props.navigator},
})
}

<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
 <TouchableHighlight
  style={styles.menuButton}
  onPress={this.goToMenu.bind(this)}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Go To Menu </Text>
 </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

> element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function for composite components but got object check render method of 'navigatorios'

Comment: something wrong with `Menu` component, can you attach its code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common error. It typically means there is an issue with the component you are importing. Check you are exporting `Menu` and importing it properly (Is the relative filepath correct). If the file path is correct...

**Default export**

```
export default () => (
     ...
);
```

Then import like this

```
import Menu from 'relativeFilePath'
```

**Named export**

Or if the file Menu is in has multiple named exports e.g.

```
export const Menu ...
export const SomeOtherComponent ...
```

You will have to deconstruct the import and match the name...

```
import {Menu} from 'relativeFilePath'
```

See more here [ES6+ javascript module export options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494365/es6-module-export-options)

If this does not work, the issue is with the Menu component you are trying to navigate to.