# ES6 export the result of a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

I am trying to export the result of a function in ES6. The function is unimportant - the following examples work for: `const func = input => input`

This works:

```
const a = 'foo'
const b = 'bar'

export default {
  a: func(a),
  b: func(b)
}
```

whereas these hit the error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ,`:

```
export {
  a: func(a),
  b: func(b)
}
```

also:

```
export {
  func(a) as a,
  func(b) as b
}
```

Could you explain why? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494365/es6-javascript-module-export-options) does not seem to cover the above cases.

Comment: can you include the original code, there's nothing wrong with the example you have given - are you using a transpiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
const aArg = 'foo'
const bArg = 'bar'

export const a = func(aArg);
export const b = func(bArg);
```

Named exports need a variable name to export, they can't export arbitrary expression results.

Comment: Thanks. I know what I can do, but I don't understand what I can't do. Why isn't `func(a) as a` equivalent to giving the result of `func(a)` a name?

Comment: `X as Y` is specifically `variable name AS variable name` so you can't call a function there. I guess it could technically be allowed, but it doesn't seem like it would come up very often since usually you're exporting a variable that exists already.

Comment: do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Henry: Grammar rules for `export`: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-exports .

Answer (score 2):

```
export default ...
```

You're exporting a single Object, Class, Function, etc.

```
export (Object, Class, Function) ...
```

You're exporting many Objects, Classes, Functions, etc. so you'll have to assign it to a name.

The first example is a little like if you teach at a school and have one student. You know who that student is and how to call him because he's the only one there. The second example, however, is like teaching a class with many students, you'll want some type of naming to call on the correct student(s).