# library not recognised in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

[clicke here to see pondjs folder inside node-modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spM8d.png)I've installed pondjs(https://www.npmjs.com/package/pondjs) using npm install pondjs --save in my react application. It's also present in package.json. I couldn't understand why in App. js when I'm doing :

```
import { TimeSeries , TimeRange} from 'pondjs';
```

it says module not installed and hence unable to recognise it's functions.

Also, I have a js file which contains lots of data in Object form  and I'm trying to import that file in App.js using :

```
import pathtofile/inputdata.js';
```

and storing in the variable as below :

```
var input_data = data;
```

IS this the right way to do in react App.js file?  Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are 2 parts to your question. I will answer them in order.

Your first question was you weren't able to call the methods of `pondjs` even though you installed it.

For that make sure that there is your `pondjs` folder inside the `node_modules` folder that will be created when you install some packages in your repository.

> **EDIT :**
>
> Are you only having issues with `pondjs` or are you facing issues with
>   all packages?
>
> If you can find the installed package in `node_modules` folder and is
>   facing the same issue for all packages, upgrade `npm`. Your problem is
>   that it doesn't search in the right folder. Try upgrading `npm` so
>   that it places files in the right spots.
>
> If it's only for `pondjs` issue might be with the package rather that
>   with your `npm` package. Make sure you read documentation right and
>   are doing in the right way.

---

Coming to your second problem.

Export the variable you want to access in the other file.

```
var obj = {
    a : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    b : { c : 'Hello World!' }
}

export var obj;
```

And call it like,

```
import { obj } from './path/to/the/file.js'
```

---

Comment: I have added a picture which shows pondjs is present inside node-modules.

Comment: in my app.js file, i can do something like this? var k = obj.a;

Comment: yes, you can. once you import it into another file, it's just same as a variable you declared in that file.

Comment: any advice on pondjs thing?

Comment: var obj = {
    a : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    b : { c : 'Hello World!' }
}

export var obj; if i do something like this, so when you hover on var obj it says duplicate declaration. Is it because while exporting your are again specifying var, so its creating a new variable.

Comment: I suppose that's the problem with your code editor. Hope you are using ES6 for coding.  If you are having problem with export here is a good reference for it https://stackoverflow.com/a/34842087/3978238

Comment: @Ashag Regarding pondjs can you specify what's the actual error message? Can you add it in the question?

Answer (score 0):

For pondjs, my code is working on Sumblime Text and Terminal. May be Webstorm IDE is not recognizing Pondjs or something.

Answer (score 0):

Use `require` instead of `import`.

`const { TimeSeries, TimeRange } = require('pondjs');`